# How can I programmatically send events to Qt's webkit?

Tags: python, qt4, browser, webbrowser-control, pyqt4

I would like to create a specialized browser that can enter certain information semi-automatically into pages that are browsed. I am using for this Qt Webkit (in particular the python bindings). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

it's doable, using javascript code-snippets.  take a look at the pyjamas-desktop "failed experiment" pyjd/pyqt4.py runtime, noting the rather important addition of the words "failed".

you would be strongly advised to avoid pywebkitqt4 for this particular purpose, instead looking at either python-hulahop (originally part of the OLPC project) or perhaps python-webkit - http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit

l.